# Using altered RewriteCond to check if file exists in multiple locations

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use mod-rewrite to check for a file in two separate locations: at the requested URL, and at the requested URL within the "public" directory.

Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$0 !-f  #this line isn't working
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

It can correctly determine if the file is there, but it's not correctly determining if the file is at /public/supplied/file/path/file.extension. How do I test for that?

Comment: Can you post which code you already have?

Comment: The broken line is the third one, that's commented "this line isn't working".

Comment: I've actually realized the problem is that public/ is not in the root directory. It is in the same directory that .htaccess is in. Is there a way to get the directory that .htaccess is in, so this can work in different locations without requiring manual modification of the .htaccess for each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've actually realized the problem is that public/ is not in the root directory. It is in the same directory that .htaccess is in. Is there a way to get the directory that .htaccess is in, so this can work in different locations without requiring manual modification of the .htaccess for each?

You can do it a subrequest. The `-F` flag will treat relative paths as relative to the directory the .htaccess is in. So:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond public/$0 !-F
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,B]
```

Note that the `-F` implies a bigger performance penalty than `-f`, since instead of just a stat, a subrequest is generated. You should also add the `B` flag to escape your back reference.

Comment: I have a similar problem.  I'm trying to check if a file exists in another directory. Does $0 stand for %{REQUEST_FILENAME}?  I can't seem to get this line to work: RewriteCond directory/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f