# .htaccess - Check if multiple files exists based on URL slug and rewrite accordingly?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slug, backreference

From the following url:

```
localhost/videos/the-best-games
```

and a directory named "categories" with various files in it located in the same directory as .htaccess :

```
./games.txt
./sports.txt
./football.txt
```

How to use the url slug "the-best-games" to check these filenames in "categories"

```
./categories/the.txt
./categories/best.txt
./categories/games.txt
```

And rewrite the url using the first matching filename:

```
localhost/games/videos/the-best-games
```

OR

```
localhost/games/videos/the-best
```

Maybe based on these previous questions:

- [htaccess: Check if a file exists based on variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297963/htaccess-check-if-a-file-exists-based-on-variables)
- [Using altered RewriteCond to check if file exists in multiple locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935156/using-altered-rewritecond-to-check-if-file-exists-in-multiple-locations)

Comment: Can URL be of unlimited length like: `http://localhost/videos/the-best-games-on-earth` and you want to check for `on.php` and `earth.php` as well?

Comment: it would be great but we can start slowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteCond /path/to/categories/$1.txt -f
RewriteRule /videos/the-best-(.*)$ /$1/videos/the-best-$1 [R,L]
```

It will parse the rule and look for the-best-(whatever), take that value and examine the file system for the file at the absolute path to your categories. Then it will do the rewrite.
If you want to remove the category from the end of the rewritten URL:

```
RewriteCond /path/to/categories/$1.txt -f
RewriteRule /videos/the-best-(.*)$ /$1/videos/the-best [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start but what about checking if the.txt and best.txt exists?